# How to call a statement after complete for/forEach loop execution having axios calls?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

This is my forEach loop. How to call a statement just after this loop is completed? I am unable to figure it out

```
array.forEach(item => {
            console.log("Loop started");
            let id = [item.id];
            let type = item.type;
            if (subType == "a") {
                api.method(type, id)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log("response.data :>> ", response.data);
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        console.log("finally item :>> ", item);
                    });
            } else if (subType == "b") {
                api.method(type, id)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log("response.data :>> ", response.data);
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        console.log("finally item :>> ", item);
                    });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since axios calls return promises. What you can do is wait for all the promises to complete.

```
let jobs: Promise<any>[] = [];
array.forEach(item => {
        console.log("Loop started");
        let id = [item.id];
        let type = item.type;
        if (subType == "a") {
            const job = api.method(type, id)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log("response.data :>> ", response.data);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    console.log("finally item :>> ", item);
                });
            jobs.push(job);
        } else if (subType == "b") {
            const job = api.method(type, id)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log("response.data :>> ", response.data);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    console.log("finally item :>> ", item);
                });
            jobs.push(job)
        }
    });
await Promise.all(jobs);
// the code here will start to execute when all promises have been resolved.
```

Comment: the line where you declared new promise is written in typescript it seems. It gives an error 'types' can only be used in a .ts file. 
Since I am a somewhat newbie in understanding the concept of promises, could you please help me in declaring it in javascript? @dilanka

Comment: `let jobs = [];`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [p-iteration](https://www.npmjs.com/p-iteration) npm module, they have custom functions for every array-loop, check this [doc](https://toniov.github.io/p-iteration/global.html#forEach) for details, you can just `await` loop or use `.then()` on it